# Input image format to Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, imageprocessing

I'm working on image processing using FPGA. My aim is to begin by performing basic image processing such as brightness control, conversion to gray scale and then later on, advance to implement the other functions as well.

In what form is it preferable to give the input image (.bmp, .bin, .hex)?

Comment: all and none of the above. **you** are building the toolchain – we can't tell you what you need, if you're not even telling us what you're doing.

Comment: My Aim is to begin by performing basic image processing such as brightness control, conversion to gray scale using FPGA and then later on, advance to implement the other functions as well.

Comment: but you're the one designing this system - we can't tell you what you'll do!

Comment: Okay I'll try to analyse the best one on my own. Thank you! Actually, I asked this to find out if there's something I need to know or be cautious about before choosing a particular format. This is my first project!

Comment: the conversion on the PC is the easy, low-effort part. Design your system, and then feed it the data it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your image processing unit is working on raw data, binary (.bin) format seems the best fit. That said, you will have to ensure that the resolution and pixel depth match what your IPU needs, which a binary file doesn’t have any information about. You’ll need to keep track of that.

.bmp format has that image format meta-information, so your test bench could reference that and extract the binary.

Hex makes no sense really. Hex encoding expands the file size by more than 2x. Hex is usually used for making PROM files.

You’ll probably want to investigate conversion tools so that you can accept a variety of formats, including jpeg, png, tiff, RAW, piecewise-linear (PWL), etc. That is, have a setup that converts them to binary as needed for your block.

Finally, get a good understanding of color spaces and gamma. sRGB is the most common, but there are others to consider depending on the end use of your processing block. More here: https://www.anandtech.com/show/13054/at-101-understanding-laptop-displays/4